# NSJSONWritingOptions explained

Tags: swift

using:

```
NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(array, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue:2))
```

Can you tell med what the `rawValue` is for?

Comment: One problem with rawValue is that unimplemented values can be passed in. It is much better to use the option name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That `rawValue` bit comes from [`OptionSetType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_OptionSetType_Protocol/index.html), from which `NSJSONWritingOptions` inherits.

Most likely you should avoid that altogether and instead use the standard Swift enum syntax, which provides a nice short constant name:

```
NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(array, options: .PrettyPrinted)
```

---

**Edit:**

To specify no options or multiple options you could use revert back to `rawValue` syntax and calculate the value yourself as you would in C, but a simpler option is the array-style syntax below:

To specify no options:

```
NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(array, options: [])
```

To combine multiple options:

```
NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [.MutableContainers, .MutableLeaves])
```

Comment: for the 'no options' case, you can actually just leave out the options param. The default [] is specified in the function definition (in swift 3 anyway)